# Ambiguous Frequency Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was browsing through the tags to look for some to edit, in the pursuit of the research assistant badge when I cam across the "frequency" tag.

It currently has 6 questions associated with it, but they both use "frequency" in a very different meaning:

- 1 question about "sound frequency"
- 1 question about "CPU frequency"
- 4 questions about "GPIO and PWM sampling frequency"

These obviously don't belong together. Should we disambiguate the "frequency" tag by making the 3 alternatives listed above?

Comment: I agree that sound, CPU, GPIO and PWM frequencies are NOT related in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this.  In addition to being a sort of "anti-tag" in the sense that it has grouped together some questions which have nothing in common (beyond the use of a word, which we might as well then have a `written-in-english` tag), to me this really seems like a spurious label.

There were actually about 30 questions with it.  Since only one had nothing else, and many of them had more appropriate existing things (e.g. [underclocking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underclocking) and/or [overclocking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overclocking)) I've removed it without creating new more specific `foo-frequency` and `bar-frequency` tags -- but I did add more specific *existing* tags to some questions.

Many of them also had the almost as spurious [measuring](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measuring) tag, but rather than remove that one as well, I created a synonym mapping for `frequency` to it.  Tags are created when added to a question (i.e., there are no tags with no questions), and the way synonyms work is if you, e.g., try now to add `frequency` you will automagically get [measuring](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measuring) and have to decide if that is appropriate.  I think this works as the non-measuring type questions were the ones with the most obvious more appropriate existing tags (clocking, audio, or RF related).

Note there's no way to actually blacklist a non-existent potential tag, other than making it a synonym.  I did at some point try to create a `pointless` tag to which certain synonyms can be mapped, but this doesn't work as it would require at least one question tagged `pointless`...'nuff said ;)

Occasionally I check the [new tags](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) page to catch things like this but alas, not often enough (and sometimes my powers of foresight fail to see how something is likely spurious).